Could the cosmological constant be the average curvature of the observable universe?
If one draws an analogy with gravitational potential and self energy in Newtonian gravity, and curved spacetime in General Relativity, could the cosmological constant be the "potential" energy of the curved spacetime inside the observable universe? It would also be equivalent to the average curvature. This would explain why the energy density of dark energy and of dark matter have the same orders of magnitude.

The cosmological constant is supposed to be constant. If the observable universe has spatial curvature, it’s presumably decreasing as the universe expands.

That analogy doesn’t make sense - the cosmological constant just tells you the density of dark energy in a given metric. Measuring potential energy for this kind of stuff in GR gets finicky, anyways…

Regarding title of the post, yes it can be done : this is the content of back reaction problem in cosmology. Cosmological constant is directly related to Ricci curvature. You can average Einstein's equation on some length scale in some appropriate sense and ask to what extent the geometry is FRW. You can then proceed to identify cc from the averaged Ricci curvature in Einstein's equation and Bianchi identity
